# Loading image freezes after submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have several JSP pages that use ajax call to do the submit and I can show a loading image before the ajax call and hide it after ajax is completed.  This way, the loading image works fine.

```
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function()
{
    $("#loadingimg").hide();
});
```

However, I have one page that doesn't use ajax call, it uses normal form action to submit the form.  When the submit button is clicked, the server will do a long time processing and the loading image becomes frozen until server comes back and direct to the next page.  How do I make the loading image not frozen while server is processing ?  Thanks a lot!

```
 <form:form id= "aForm" name="aForm"  method="post" modelAttribute="attr" 
   action="submit.htm" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your image in an iframe, the submit button makes the page stops, but iframe should continue to run. Then show/hide the iframe something like:

```
<iframe src="<yourimageurl>" id="loading"></iframe>

$("aForm").submit(function (){
   $("#loading").show();
});
```